# Pagination Adding Numbers in Strange Fashion

Tags: pagination

Below is my pagination code.  It can be seen in action at [this link](http://themeforward.com/demo2/?paged=1).  When I start on page one it displays the first 3 pages and page 9 (the last page).  When I go to the second it displays the first 4 and page 9.  I find this to be odd behavior and expect the numbers to be added in a traditional behavior, [like that code found on CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/archives/). Does anybody know what I've done incorrectly in my code below?

```
 // the block for pagination
        global $wp_query;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        echo paginate_links(
            array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), 
                'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
            )
        );
```

Comment: Did you get this from a specific article, if so can you please name it and link to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing, I believe, is a  result of [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) using three blocks of numbering-- first, middle, and last. If you had enough pages you'd get, for example, when browsing page 50 ...

> *1 2 3 ... 49 **50** 51 ... 98 99 100*

If you imagine the "middle" numbers overlapping the "first" numbers you'd get 3 or 4 or five numbers bunched up. You can play with the `end_size` and `mid_size` parameters and try to get something you like better, or use `'type' => 'array'` and write your own display function to convert the resulting array into actual pagination links.